# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 7 nodes produced errors; first error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found

Tags: doparallel

I'm attempting to run an r script across multiple cores and everything seems to work, however when I change where I install my packages (reset the `libpath` to a project folder instead my home directory) I get the following error.

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :
7 nodes produced errors; first error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found
```

I'm confused as I am running this across multiple cores, not multiple nodes

```
cores=detectCores()
c1 <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1)
registerDoParallel(c1)
```

What am I doing wrong and why does the package location matter?